# Didn’t Turing simply expand the space of algorithmic problems?

Tags: language, computation, turing

Code breaking brings the realization that, for the other side to generate their code (used my multiple people, not a private language), there must be an “algorithm”.

Jacquard machines, analog Pong, etc are computational, yet they don’t immediately make us suspect so many things may have algorithms.

So it seems like it was the self-reflexivity of other humans’ activities which must have an algorithm that “exploded” what we think may be computational.

**It seems like as soon as we say there are algorithms, there is universal computation [of algorithms]**. Thus what Turing really did was convince us many more things can be algorithmic as we’ve had algorithms (long division) for thousands of years. I don’t see the need for the abstract Turing tape machine.

So was Turing’s insight that many many more things have algorithms, largely from the public nature of code breaking as an example? And not something about computation itself.

Comment: Turing's invention of Turing machines predated his codebreaking work by a number of years. I'm not sure why you're conflating the two. His motivation in developing the TM concept was to solve the Entscheidungsproblem, the question of whether or not a given logical statement can be proven from axioms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem

Comment: @user4894 isn’t that more what an algorithm can’t do? We’ve had algorithms for a long time since long division and sieve of Eratosthenes, and some notion of what algorithms can’t do. The amount problems that can be solved with algorithms grew exponentially and this century. I don’t think it’s because of what algorithms *cant* do. I guess code breaking is wrong though, it’s more general, about formal alphabets/language. I guess we still would have gotten TM’s without needing to break codes.

Comment: We DID get TMs without needing to break codes. That's the historical chronology. Turing used the TM idea to show that the Entscheidungsproblem could not be solved with any algorithm. Alonzo Church used the lambda calculus to show the same thing, beating Turing by a few months.

Comment: @user4894 help me understand the state of affairs then. Pre 1935 we had algorithms and knew some things can’t be algorithmic/computable—surely “paint a painting which evokes late capitalist malaise to the children at Oxfam” has no algorithm. We already have those two classes pre 1935. I’m still stuck on the very idea of an algorithm doing ALL of the work toward UTM’s since we get those two classes for free with the concept of algorithm. We can know something has an algorithm even without knowing it specifically. Since it has an algorithm, it is computable, and in a finite time. Seems universal

Comment: Wiki has a pretty clear answer to your question. "It was the second proof (after Church's theorem) of the conjecture that some purely mathematical yes–no questions can never be answered by computation; more technically, that some decision problems are "undecidable" in the sense that there is no single algorithm that infallibly gives a correct "yes" or "no" answer to each instance of the problem." Before Turing, it was hoped that there could be a mechanical or algorithmic decision procedure ("effective procedure" in the parlance of the day) to solve any *mathematical* question. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Turing and Church showed that there is not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing%27s_proof

Comment: @user4894 thank you for that quote. It took another year after the decision problem (36-37) for UTMs tho according to wiki. My main overall question (muddied by trying to tie to code breaking) remains: knowing there exist algorithmic and non algorithmic problems (not  about math) was known earlier. That algorithms exist, it then seems unavoidable to get the universal part too. I don’t get how that took till 36-37. If something followed clear steps, anything else which can follow clear steps can too.

Comment: Can't add much. FWIW the result was in the air. Gödel published his incompleteness theorems in 1931.

Answer (score -1):

Universal computation grew out of code breaking because 1) it was realized that computers could test possible code keys far faster than any human could and 2) such computers had to be *reprogrammable* to handle changes in the code keys, which were happening all the time.

Then, in walks a genius in the form of Alan Turing and he realizes that you could go a level of abstraction above a specific sort of computer running a certain sort of program to accomplish a specific type of task and then contemplate an "ubercomputer" than could run *any* program to accomplish *any* sort of computational task.

Comment: I guess I’m wondering where the “reverse engineer” aspect fits in. Codes are necessarily reverse-engineerable, but “he drew a painting which evoked late capitalism malaise to students at Oxfam” is not always. Maybe the painter didn’t intend such reaction. Maybe no one can compute (no algorithm) for what the audience will think. Is that touched upon here? Did we have such classes as computational and noncomputational *and then* Turing abstraction. Or are they one in the same?

Comment: As in, as soon as I recognize there are computational problems, is the idea of universal computation a rider, or not? Or am I mixing too much up?

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Universal computation did not grow out of code breaking, theoretical models of computation were not invented to solve practical problems, and Turing was not unusual in contemplating the notion of an abstract computing machine, lots of people were doing it; and Turing's was neither the first nor the best.